# JAVAFX tableview : Update all the values in single column with new value

Tags: javafx, tableview

I am very new to javaFX technology. I have created one tableview which is having multiple columns. Now I have a requirement where I need to replace all the values in one of the column with one new value. How to achive this in javaFX. The new value which will replace all the values in that table coloumn is coming from one pop up.

Comment: How do you populate data in your table? Using observables from FXCollections?

Comment: update your model then call tableView.refresh(); (works with javafx 1.8.60+)

Comment: yes I am populating the table using Using observables from FXCollections

Comment: @AjitkumarPatil In that case all you need to do is set the properties (see my answer): there is no need to call `refresh()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the appropriate property for each item in the table:

```
table.getItems().forEach(item -> item.someProperty().set(someValue));
```

where `someProperty()` is the property accessor method for the property in the column of interest, and `someValue` is the value you're setting it to.